# After merging dicts in a list how can I convert it back to type dict not string?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

hi there i have a list of dicts

```
dict = [{A: 2}, {B: 2},]
```

i am trying to merge them together like this

```
dict = [{A: 2, B: 2}]
```

i try doing it using this code

```
new_dict = ', '.join([str(x) for x in dict])
```

the problem i have now is my list of object is now a string . so when i run this code below

```
    for k, v in sorted(new_dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True):
        rtn_value[k] = v
        count = count - 1
        if count == 0: return rtn_value
```

I get this ERROR

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

after merging objects in a list how can I convert it back to type dict not string?

when i do type(new_dict) ...i can see it is a type string

```
new_dict <class 'str'>
```

Comment: Don't use `dict` for a variable name.  It blocks the builtin `dict`, which is a bad idea in general but is especially bad when you're actually *using* dicts.

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/223254). You're asking us about how to deal with your string and convert it back to a dictionary, but the real question seems to be how to merge dictionaries, which probably shouldn't involve strings concatenation in the first place.

Comment: Try this:  `new_dict = {k:v for d in dict_list for k, v in d.items()}` where `dict_list` if your original dict list.

Comment: You could also use `functools.reduce` to merge/fold them all into 1 in a single statement: `new_dict = reduce(lambda x,y: {**x,**y}, dict_list)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
result = {}
for item in dict:
    result.update(item)
result = [result]
```

Note however that

1. you better not use reserved word `dict` as your variable
2. you probably want dictionary keys to be strings ("A", not A)
3. you haven't told us what should be the result when you have the same key in multiple dictionaries
4. most likely you don't need the last step of wrapping the result in a list

Comment: iam using dict as a variable in my example but my code i am not

Comment: `dict` isn't a reserved word (if it were, it would not be possible to assign to it).  It's the name of a builtin.  A reserved word would be a syntactic element, such as `if` or `else` or `while` or `class` etc.  But you still don't want to use `dict` as a variable name, since it blocks the builtin.

Comment: Builtin, yes, though that was not my point.

Answer (score 0):

" This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/223254). You're asking us about how to deal with your string and convert it back to a dictionary, but the real question seems to be how to merge dictionaries, which probably shouldn't involve strings concatenation in the first place." – [Blckknght](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1405065/blckknght)

I agree with what he said in his comment. But for some reason you must convert a string back to dictionary, you can use the **ast** library.

```
from ast import literal_eval
dict_ = [{'A': 2}, {'B': 2},]

new_dict = ','.join([str(x) for x in dict_])
new_dict = list(literal_eval(new_dict))
```